# How to use xlsxwriter to add colors to specified numbers of columns in a row?

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

[image]I want to add colors to specified numbers of columns(the cells which have contents) in a row, but when I use worksheet.set_row(21, None, color_format), it will apply to a whole row.